# Measuring internet data transfers

Tags: python, symbian, pys60

Is there any way in python for S60 (using the python 2.5.4 codebase) to track the amount of data transferred over the mobile device's internet connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symbian C++ API has such a capability, so it is possible to write a python library for that, but if such already exists, that I do not know...
BR
STeN